# Grabbing onClick Value with PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, onclick, html-table, href

I have been working on one small project, where I am trying to grab onClick value from HTML code. Unfortunately, after reading some post, that I should use pre_match, didn't work.

Maybe someone could help me here and help me find a way?

```
 <div class="results">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr class="resultName">
                <td>1st</td>
                <td>2nd</td>
                <td>3rd</td>
                <td>4th</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1stText</td>
                        <td>2ndText</td>
                        <td>3rdText</td>
                        <td>4thText</td>
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="openWin('/link.html','Results',{width:341,height:550}); return false;">Results</a></td>
                    </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

I was only able to grab text content "Results".

P.s Found a way of this:

```
$linkcounter = 0;

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link){
                        if ($link->getAttribute('href') == "#" && $link->getAttribute('onclick')){

                            echo "linkcounter - ".$linkcounter." ".$link->getAttribute('onclick')."</br>";
                            $linkcounter++;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
<a href="#" class="get_value" onclick="openWin('/link.html','Results',{width:341,height:550}); return false;">Results</a>
```

and in JS

```
$(function(){
 $(".get_value").click(function(){

   var onclickValue = $(this).attr("onclick");
 })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. Unfortunately, this is only part of HTML content, there are plenty of "tr" content inside and I want to parse all this data to my server dynamically. Text part is done, struggling with onClick part unfortunately..

Comment: OP didn't tag JQuery and didn't post any jquery code in the question, so even though jquery may be a viable solution, you should stick to pure Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't grab a value "on click". That would be JavaScript. PHP can only grab values passed via $_POST or $_GET.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php